# T-SQL - CROSS APPLY to a PIVOT? (using pivot with a table-valued function)?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, user-defined-functions

I have a table-valued function, basically a split-type function, that returns up to 4 rows per string of data.

So I run:

```
select * from dbo.split('a','1,a15,b20,c40;2,a25,d30;3,e50')
```

I get:

```
Seq  Data
1    15
2    25
```

However, my end data needs to look like

```
15 25
```

so I do a pivot.

```
select [1],[2],[3],[4] 
from dbo.split('a','1,a15,b20,c40;2,a25,d30;3,e50')
pivot (max(data) for seq in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) 
as pivottable
```

which works as expected:

```
1    2
---  ---
15   25
```

HOWEVER, that's great for one row.  I now need to do it for several hundred records at once.  My thought is to do a CROSS APPLY, but not sure how to combine a CROSS APPLY and a PIVOT.

(yes, obviously the easy answer is to write a modified version that returns 4 columns, but that's not a great option for other reasons)

Any help greatly appreciated.

And the reason I'm doing this: the current query uses as scalar-valued version of SPLIT, called 12 times within the same SELECT against the same million rows (where the data string is 500+ bytes).

So far as I know, that would require it scan the same 500bytes * 1000000rows, 12 times.

Comment: And the reason I'm doing this: due to the amount of logic in dbo.SPLIT (what's above is a drastic simplication), I'm trying to avoid running the scalar-valued function version of SPLIT, which looks like `select dbo.split('a',1,'1,a15,b20,c40;2,a25,d30;3,e50')`, and winds up being called 12 times ("'a',1", "'a',2","'a',3","'a',4","'c',1","'c'2",...),.  Which, when queried against a table with a million rows, has got to be A Bad Thing.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding something...you would need to call the function with new parameters anyway so a CROSS APPLY won't help you. How are the parameters being passed into the function in the first place? Can you give an overview of the process involved?

Comment: instead of using parameters, I want to feed it a field from a table. The current process basically looks like `select a,b,dbo.splitscalar('a',1,stringofdata), dbo.splitscalar('a', 2, stringofdata), dbo.splitscalar('b',1,stringofdata)...` (12 times total), and since the string is several hundred bytes, I figure changing to the CROSS APPLY and calling the function 3 times instead might be faster.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question directly, I used [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) to dynamically create columns for the pivot table. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you use cross apply. Assume `table1` is your table and `Line` is the field in your table you want to split

```
SELECT * fROM table1 as a
    cross apply dbo.split(a.Line) as b  
    pivot (max(data) for seq in ([1],[2],[3],[4]))  as p
```